# Starting java program and screen with cron at boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, gnu-screen

I am trying to run a java program inside a screen session at boot, I am using the following cron, but after reboot screen -ls shows no active screen sessions.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmS myservice "java -jar /home/david/myservice/MyService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

I did change it to the following and the screen does start at boot now.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -dmS myservice && "java -jar /home/david/myservice/MyService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

I added `&&` before starting the java command and not the screen does start at boot. But the program is still not running.

but the program is not running when I attach to the screen. after attaching to the screen all I see is a dollar sign.

Comment: Don't run services in `screen`. It is not reliable for production use, and it is not a service manager anyway. Start them properly, e.g. from a systemd unit.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the reason I want to run it on screen is because I want to be able to see the output on screen without having to use log files

Comment: Don't do that. You need to learn how to use logs to see the output. Using screen means you actually can't see logs because they aren't saved anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your distro, or your implementation of `cron`, doesn't support `@reboot` at all, or fully, or for all users. It's a tricky one.

`screen` might not be a good way to launch a service either, but either way, I'd recommend an alternative to `cron` for this. [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples) covers initialising services at boot across a few different system configurations, and might be what you need.

Comment: Can you please check the edited section of my question please